# By Pass Security Warning for website

Tags: android, appium, selenium-chromedriver

4.13.1 with android emulator 6.0.
When accessing my company produced website using default, as I will have pop up Security Warning : There are problems with the security certificate for this site. With selection of "Go Back/View certificate/Continue".
If there anyway I can set capabilities when running android default browser to accept and continue?
Or there is alternative way?

Comment: Following contains the info on troubleshooting the Appium issues. https://debugger89.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/troubleshooting-ios-web-application-automation-with-safari/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solutions, as I switch the capability to test on android instead of web, with this even though have to map again all the id and xpath information but this will work.